# I set a gradient for my div, and it is stretching to contain the div which looks hideous. How 2 fix?

Tags: html, css, gradient, linear-gradients

```css
div {
  color: white;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
        180deg,
        rgba(108, 133, 141, 1) 0%,
        rgba(108, 133, 141, 1) 4%,
        rgba(10, 54, 67, 1) 5%,
        rgba(10, 54, 67, 1) 16%,
        rgba(10, 54, 67, 1) 58%,
        rgba(10, 54, 67, 1) 93%,
        rgba(6, 33, 40, 1) 93%,
        rgba(6, 33, 40, 1) 95%,
        rgba(6, 33, 40, 1) 98%);

  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 10px;
  
  width: 50%;
  height: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello.</div>
```

I’ve tried background-attachment, background-cover, object-fit, all that but they never work. I’ve seen websites do this without problem so I know I can do it aswell.

Comment: It looks fine to me - what's so "hideous" about it?

Comment: Are you talking about the width values?  Maybe what you want is display: inline-block; and width: auto?

Comment: Make the height of the div 500px, you’ll see.